# Img modal only opening first img

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I am trying to list multiple images on a page with the below, whereas when you click the image it opens in modal.

It is working for the first image but no others, I am assuming it's a JS issue, I've tried setting an empty var then setting it to get the element id (which is the same for each img) but again only the first works.

```
<?php foreach ($img as $thumbnail) {
  echo '<img id="myImg" src="'.$thumbnail.'" width="300" height="200">
    <div id="imgModal" class="modal">
      <span class="closeModal">&times;</span>
      <img class="modal-content" id="myImg1">
    <div id="caption"></div>
  </div>
  <span class="closeModal">&times;</span>';  
}
?>
<script>
  var modal = document.getElementById('imgModal');

  var img = document.getElementById('myImg');
  var modalImg = document.getElementById("myImg1");
  img.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = this.src;
  }

  var span = document.getElementsByClassName("closeModal")[0];

  span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Diversify your `id` attributes. `id`s must be unique.

Comment: `id` must be unique.

Comment: Does the `name` attribute need to be unique?

Comment: @SaucedApples no, `id` only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code includes the same **`id`** attribute for different elements but **`id` must be unique.**

`id` attribute specifies a unique identifier for an HTML element so you can manipulate it via JS or CSS. If you are using the same `id` for different elements you will only get the first one on the page.

If you want to add event listener to multiple elements add a `class` to your `<img>`:

```
echo '<img id="myImg" src="'.$thumbnail.'" width="300" height="200" class="modal-img">
```

And after that add event listener for every element with a class `modal-img`.

Comment: *E.g:* `var modalImg = document.getElementsByClassName('modal-img');` **OR**  declare a `php` variable that you increment in the `foreach` loop then append that variable to the end of your `id` attribute value for every item in the loop.